# React.js useState values do not match asynchronously

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-state

I'm having an odd issue where some times the value passed into `useState` is not the same as the variable for `useState`. This happens on the same UI component each time while others are not having the issue. Just wanted to double check if I'm doing anything wrong here.

```
// userData is from Redux store
const {userData} = props 

const [installed, setInstalled] = useState(userData.installed)  // installed: boolean

console.log(userData.installed) // returns true
console.log(installed) // returns false
console.log(userData) // installed: true
```

Reason I'm using useState is because I'm using it to render a button that will be toggled, as well as displaying an indicator whether it is toggled or not.

```
<Button onClick={() => setInstalled(!installed) />
```

Comment: This would only set installed on mount, no further changes would apply to the state variable. Why do you want to copy a prop value into state?

Comment: It's likely that `installed` is initially `false` before changing to `true`, but once initialized, `useState` ignores the value passed as an argument.

Comment: If I recall, useState can handle async functions so it would update when the response is sent back. 90% of the time, I don't see any issues and it will usually render correctly, but the same component displays what I've shown above. Also edited OP for context.

Comment: for the click handler you should do `() => setInstalled(prevInstalled => !prevInstalled)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to use `useEffect` to watch the state inside your Redux store then update the local state based on that changes :

```
const [userData] = props ;
const [installed, setInstalled] = useState(userData.installed)

useEffect(() => {
  setInstalled(userData.installed)
},[userData])
```

Comment: This solved the issue. If I understand it correct, useEffect is called when component is mounted. It then updates the value of `installed` using `userData`. This is because useState's initial value may not be correct as it's an async function. Right?

Comment: it observes the userData changes and it's called in mounted and when the userData will change